Which of Two Lighting Solutions Will Use More Computational Resources?
If in one Blender project I have a cube that is lit up by a sunlight light type, and in a second Blender project I have a cube that has its own light emission to light itself up, which project would use the most computing resources/memory?
In addition: With a mesh object emission, is there a way to make it both static and to stop the object from emitting light onto other mesh objects?

Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

@DuarteFarrajotaRamos The title does match the content of the post. It mentions the word 'question' because it is a question..

@MarkRoe The titles here all belong to questions, because that is what this site is about, asking questions. So mentioning that it is a question is redundant.  And more important: you are aware that "Lighting" can be about thousands of topics and not everybody is familiar with every aspect of lighting. That is why you are asked to be more specific about your problem in the title to indicate others if they think they might be able to help or not without having to read every question. Another thing is, on this site we usually deal with one problem per thread, not a list of problems.

It matches the content but is not very specific, this could fit any of the thousands of questions about lighting we have here. In addition to what Gordon mentioned, The first part of your question also seems like something you could easily test and see for yourself.

I think it might be appropriate for my account to be deleted here as the ability to choose certain words is obviously policed very heavily. Not my style and not something i've seen anywhere else to this macabre extent

@MarkRoe, try answering a couple of hundred questions here. You will see that it makes a lot of sense to ask people for descriptive titles. Every post is a question, every case is asking for help, in every case there is a problem to be solved and yet there are titles "Can anyone help me with this problem?" and similar that convey no or limited information. These requests are not to censor your thoughts, they are to improve the quality of your communication. The clearer you communicate your question the better we are able to help. Spend some time on this platform and you will see for yourself.
